# Regular functions on cotangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ and $T^*X$ be its co-tangent bundle.

Question: Is there any way to compute $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{T^*X})$? Or can we put some condition on $X$ such that we can always find $n$-independent regular functions on $TX$ ?

Comment: We have $H^0 (O_{T^*X}) = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} H^0(X, Sym^n(TX))$. I'm not sure this formula simplifies if $X$ is Fano (but I might be wrong).

Comment: You should have a look at [this paper](https://math.unice.fr/~hoering/articles/a37-pseff-tangent.pdf) and the references therein. It shows in particular that $H^0(\mathscr{O}_{T^*X})=\mathbb{C}$ for a smooth hypersurface of degree $\geq 3$, while the answer to your question is positive for *toric* varieties.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.